# Firefox 'forgetting' my logins after closing

Tags: firefox, browser, passwords

A prime example of the above is logging into SO/SF/MSO/SU.  I use myopenid and have an SSL Client Certificate, but each time I start FF I have to login.  This happens for my Yahoo, GMail, etc as well.

I'm not clearing my settings on close for FF, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you disabled cookies?

Comment: @Perspx: Cookies are on (and they smell gooood!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem recently, I'm not sure what caused it, but I found uninstalling and then reinstalling Firefox fixed the problem.  Don't forget to backup your bookmarks beforehand.

For what it's worth, this was with Firefox 3 (3.0, I think) on Windows Vista 64.

([obligatory](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpmLrz_lSuE))

Comment: Love the link!  I'll give it a shot and let you know...

Comment: Whatever it was, a full uninstall and reinstall fixed it up!  Thanks!  Yes, I know I should have done it before asking, but I was hoping that I wouldn't have to re-setup all the add-on's I had... :-\

Answer (score 1):

Are you flushing your cookies at exit? check the firefox privacy configurations.
This would also happen if you do not have rights to save in your windows login or
If you have roaming profiles (not usually likely) that are not sync'ed properly.

Comment: I've checked and no. Thanks for reminding me though, you never know what you might forget!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a third-party "Internet security" program installed that deletes all your cookies for you -- hard to say without seeing your computer. Your issue seems to be cookie related.

Comment: I only have McAfee Corp installed as Anti-Virus, but have Ad-Aware AE and SpyBot Search & Destroy installed for adware/malware/spyware.  None of these have automatically cleared out the cookies and I haven't done it manually.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

The original issue was solved but in case someone else has similar problems: Check `privacy.clearOnShutdown.*` settings in `about:config`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem on a family member's computer recently; deleting `cookies.sqlite` from Firefox's profile directory fixed the problem. (Oddly, clearing cookies from within the Firefox UI didn't fix it -- the DB file itself had to be removed).